# How to get the text box instead of dropdown select box if get null value from json

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I get the json data from controller and show in dropdown select box.but when i get the null value in json i want to show text box instead of dropdown. to fill data manually.

```
    public function getyear(Request $request){
    $appraisals=new Appraisals();
    $serial=$_GET['ser'];
    $brand=$_GET['brand'];

    $year_array='';

    $serial_number=$appraisals->get_years($brand,$serial);


    if(isset($serial_number)):
    foreach($serial_number as $years):

    $yrs=$years->year_start;
    $yre=$years->year_end;
    endforeach;
    endif;
    if(!empty($serial_number)){
        if($yrs!="" && $yre!=""){

            for($i=$yrs;$i<=$yre;$i++):

            $year_array.="<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
            endfor;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //for($i=1840;$i<1940;$i++):
        $year_array.="<input type='text' value=''>";
        //endfor;

    }


    return response()->json(['success' => true,'years_array'=>$year_array]);
    exit;
}
```

java script function:

```
   $('#serial').blur(function() {
         var ser=$(this).val();
         var brand=$('#brand').val();

         brand = brand.split('%') ;

         $.getJSON("{!! URL::route('appraisal.getyear') !!}", {brand: brand[0],ser:ser}, function(data) {


             if(data.success)
                {

                $('#year').html(data.years_array);

                }

            });

        });
```

view file:

```
  <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Serial number</label>
                    {{Form::text('serial_number', null, ['placeholder' => 'Enter serial no','class'=>'form-control','id'=>'serial'])}}
                </div>


                  <div class="form-group" id="yeartext">
                    <label>Select Year</label>
                    <span class="years"></span>
                    @if($years=="")
                    {{Form::text('year', null, ['placeholder' => 'Enter Year no','class'=>'form-control','id'=>'year'])}}   
                    @else
                    {{Form::select('year',$years,  null, ['placeholder' => 'Pick a year','class'=>'form-control','id'=>'year'])}}
                    @endif
                </div>
```

How to show the text box instead of select box i not get any tutorial for that so any help would be greatly appricated.

Comment: just try if(strlen($year)) true show select false show textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have one soluation for your question

Firsly just re-create the whole 
Element in your controller on your GetJson Request 
and one thing you need to use $.get method on   $.getJSON

```
$year_array='';
$year_array.="<label>Select Year</label>";
$year_array.="<span class='years'></span>";
if(!empty($serial_number)){
    if($yrs!="" && $yre!=""){
        $year_array.="<select name='year'>";
        for($i=$yrs;$i<=$yre;$i++):
        $year_array.="<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
        endfor;
        $year_array.="</select>";
    }
}
else
{
    $year_array.="<input type='text' value=''>";
}
```

than add html on your 'yeartext' div

```
$("#yeartext").html(data.years_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a very semplified version of your code, only to let you understand the concept:

**Controller:**

```
public function getyear(Request $request){

    $years_array = [];
    if(isset($request->brand)){
        for($i = 1900; $i<2001; $i++ ){
            $years_array[] = $i;
        }
    }

    $response['success'] = true;
    $response['empty'] = empty($years_array);

    if(!empty($years_array)) $response['years_array'] = $years_array;


    return response()->json($response);
}
```

Javascript:

```
$.getJSON("{!! URL::route('appraisal.getyear') !!}", {brand: brand[0],ser:ser}, function(data) {
    if(data.success === false) return;

    $year_container = $('#yeartext');
    if(data.empty === false){
        $select = $('<select></select>')

        for(i=0; i<data.years_array.length; i++){
            $select.append('<option value="'+ data.years_array[i] +'">'+ data.years_array[i] +'</option>')
        }

        $year_container.append($select);
    }

    else{
        $year_container.append('<input type="text" name="year"');

    }

});
```